# Struts2 - How to populate a select tag with a list of String?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have a select that has to populate its options with a list of String. The option value and text are to be equals.

I know that I'm sending the list correctly because the select render a number of elements equals to the size of the list.

```
<s:select name="status" list="status" headerKey="" headerValue="-- Select --" id="status" listKey="" listValue="" />
```

What happens is that the options are rendered without value and text because I don't have a clue about what I should refer to in `listKey` and `listValue` attributes of the select tag of Struts2 taglib.

**The method in the action:**

```
public List<String> getStatus() {
    return Arrays.asList("Active", "Inactive");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you omit the `lisKey` and `listValue` attributes, then Struts2 will use the string text as the key and the value.

Try:

```
<s:select name="status" list="status" headerKey="" headerValue="-- Select --" id="status" />
```